# Count number of items in one databasefield

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table in my MySQL database called `Sponsors`.
This table has a two field. `event` and `names`. The field `names` is filled with different words. For example `Pieter, Sam, Thomas`. I would like to count the number of names in `names`.

How can I do this using PHP and SQL-requests. I though something like this...

```
$query = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT names FROM Sponsors WHERE id = '55'"));
$result = str_replace(',',' ', $query);
$total = count($result);
```

But this didn't solve it...

**EDIT**

```
if(!empty($activiteiten))
    {
        foreach($activiteiten as $k => $v) 
            {
                $query = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT aanwezig FROM tblLeidingAgenda WHERE id = "'.$v["id"].'"),0');
                $result = str_replace(", ", " ", $query);
                $total = str_word_count($result);

                echo '<div class="lof-main-item">';
                echo '<img src="images/791902news3.jpg" title="Newsflash 2" height="300" width="900">           
                            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 2" href="#">'.$v["uur"].'</a></h3>
                        <p>'.$v["titel"].'</p>
                        ID: '.$v["id"].'
                    <form method="post" action="#">
                        <input type="submit" name="aanwezig" value="Ik ben aanwezig"/><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="afwezig" value="Ik ben afwezig"/><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="herinnering" value="Stuur herinnering"/><br />
                        <input type="text" name="id" value="'.$v["id"].'" />
                        Ik ben aanwezig ('.$total.'): '.$v["aanwezig"].'<br />
                        Ik ben afwezig: '.$v["afwezig"].'</form></div></div> ';
            }
    }
```

Comment: Normalize your database. One table for events, one for sponsor names, and one to link the two together (event - sponsor, one set per row, so multiple rows per event).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the number of rows:

```
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

[PHP Manual (mysql_num_rows)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Or `SELECT COUNT(*)` in the first place.

**Edit**

Oh nevermind, it looks like you're storing a comma separated list right in a single cell. That's a bad practice btw. You probably just need another MySQL table to store them properly. If you decide not to fix database schemat though this should work for you:

```
$query = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT names FROM Sponsors WHERE id = '55'"));
$result = explode(',',$query);
$total = count($result);
```

[PHP Manual (explode)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, but I get an `Array`-return. So the result is stated `Array`. Should I fetch it?

Comment: @Michiel That's what explode does, it returns an array, take a look at the manual for explode. `count()` counts the number of elements in an array, so $total should contain the number of names. (It will contain the number of commas in your string plus 1)

Comment: Ok, next error :) `Warning: mysql_result() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /customers/9/7/5/***.php on line 5` I thought it was solved by adding something like `,0,'names'` correct?
By the way, still getting the `Array` result... Even with the `explode`

Comment: @ah yes, you need to specify the row to read a value from. I'm assuming you're only selecting one row with your query, since you have an id equivalence comparison. You don't need to specify names since you only fetch one column (but you can): `mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT names FROM Sponsors WHERE id = '55'"), 0);`

Comment: By the way, can I add this within a `if`-statement?

Comment: Yet, it's giving an error... See my edit in my original post. The page turns out to be blank! Don't mind the naming. It's Dutch :)

Comment: @Michiel There is no point wrapping that in that if statement since the foreach wont run if it is empty. Are you sure there is content in `$activiteiten`? What does putting `var_dump($activiteiten)` before all that code give you?

Comment: the `var_dump` doesn't do much. And `$activiteiten` isn't empty... I have to get the `id` variable to the activity. That's why I thought putting it in the `if`-statement

Comment: What exactly does `var_dump` output?

Comment: Not much. I get a nice `NULL` in the top of my page... What should this snippet do?

Comment: @Michiel it tells you what's in the variable, if it outputs NULL that means there is nothing in `$activiteiten`, not even an empty array. Why do you think it's not empty?

Comment: No, my bad. I placed the snippet before `$activiteiten` got it's value. Right now (when placing the `var_dump` àfter the declaration, I get an very long array of all the values in the database

Comment: @Michiel Hmm... I'm not sure then. Oh wait, you have an error. You have an `'` after your 0 in `mysql_result()`. You shouldn't have a `'` there, that is a syntax error

Comment: @michiel instead you should put the `'` between the `"` and the `)` so you have `"'), 0);`

Comment: Ok, I think you just gave me the solution :) Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: @Michiel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2875/discussion-between-paulpro-and-michiel)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$query = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT names FROM tblLeidingAgenda WHERE id = '55'"), 0, 'names');
$result = explode(',' $query);
$total = count($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PaulPRO I came to this solving solution

```
$query = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT afwezig FROM tblLeidingAgenda WHERE id = '55'"),0);
$result = str_replace(", ", " ", $query);
$total = str_word_count($result);
```

I'm not sure if it's correct, feel free to correct me